# Im trying to create a spanish to english translator and am using urllib

Tags: python, urllib

My problem is that I'm trying to find a wildcard in the search as the answer to each input can be different.

Here's the code:

```
import urllib.request, re, fnmatch

while True:

word = input('Enter your word: ')

url = 'http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/' + word

u = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

decoded = u.decode('utf-8')

search_1 = re.search('<span class="context">', decoded)
search_2 = re.search('</span>&nbsp;', decoded)

start = search_1.end()
end = search_2.start()


final = decoded[start:end]

search_3 = re.search('<a href="/translate/', decoded)
search_4 = re.search('</a>', decoded)


start_2 = search_3.end()
end_2 = search_4.start()

final_2 = decoded[start_2:end_2]

print(final)
print(regex)
```

The problem is that the script I'm making can't find the translated word as their is obviously more than one `</a>` in the html code.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Also, don't use `re` to parse HTML. Have a look at [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: Can't agree more on using BeautifulSoup / XPath